# To find and assign primes to an array

Tags: c

Hi I have made a simple program to print primes between 1 and 100 but I cannot figure a way to assign these values to an array of size 25 as we all know there are 25 primes between 1 and 100:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   int i, k;
   for (i = 3; i < 100; i = i + 2) {
      for (k = 2; k < i; k++) {
         if (i % k == 0)
             break;
      }
      if (i == k)
         printf("%d\n", i);
   }
}
```

Comment: You do print the primes. Can you count while printing? Is your problem to define and write-access an array? That would mean you are basically asking for a tutorial on arrays, which would be off-topic. So what is it you neeed help with?This makes the question so unclear that it is off-topic in another way.

Comment: @bstrauch24 I rejected your proposed edit because it does not just format the code properly but changes the **actual code** and as such is an attempt to reply in the wrong place.

Comment: To find primes [1...100],  I'd expect `for(i=2;i<100;i++)`

Comment: @WeatherVane the only change was to move the declaration of `int i` into the for loop

Comment: Yes, that's an attempt to reply. Don't "correct" the code in an edit.

Comment: To improve speed [quadratically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_growth), use `for (k=2; k<=i/k; k++)`.

Comment: @chux to improve speed, use `for (k = 3; k * k <= i; k += 2)` having marked `2` as the only even prime.

Comment: @WeatherVane `k += 2` is, at best, is a minor liner improvement.  Try profiling , as not likely to improve performance much at all as the even numbers quickly fall out in the first iteration.  `k * k <= i` has the weakness than `k*k` may overflow before the loop ends.  `k<=i/k` may be faster than `k * k` as the next line of code is  `i%k` and good compilers do`i/k, i%k` for the cost of one.  Of course with `n < 100`, such learner code is not performance driven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an array at the top, write to it, and then read out of it after you've found all your primes. Note that this could definitely be done more efficiently, but given the number of calculations you're doing, that's beside the point.

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

  int primes[25];
  int i, k;
  int j = 0;

  // find primes
  for(i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
    for (k = 2; k < i; k++) {
      if (i % k == 0) {
        break;
      }
    }

    if (i == k) {
        primes[j] = i;
        j++;
    }
  }

  // print primes
  for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
      printf("%d\n", primes[j]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Also note that 2 is prime, so you'll want to make sure that that's included in your output.

**Output**

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
```

Comment: @SAYANGHOSH Please feel free to accept if this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array before you begin, then create a variable that increments while each prime is found. It might look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int primes[25];
    primes[0] = 2;
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 3; i < 100; i += 2) {
        int k;
        for (k = 2; k < i; k++) {
            if (i % k == 0) break;
        }
        if(i == k) {
            primes[count] = i;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This program outputs nothing. Please show the result.

Comment: Following the edit of `2` as a prepared result, what is the point of iterating `k` from `2` and including every even divisor?

Comment: Hmm, "printing primes between 1 and 100" and "we all know there are 25 primes" leads this code to end with `count = 24`.  It misses `2` and lacks any output.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this is a humorous answer, not to be taken seriously.

Just like we all know there are 25 primes between 1 and 100, we might as well know the magic value to avoid using an array at all:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long long magic = 150964650272183;
    printf("2");
    for (int i = 3; magic; magic >>= 1, i += 2)
        magic & 1 && printf(" %d", i);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97`

Comment: @AlexJohnson: the trick was too obvious: I added an extra twist of wonder.